# Need fresh eyes for Java regular expression, which is too greedy

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

I have a string of the form:

```
canonical_class_name[key1="value1",key2="value2",key3="value3",...]
```

The purpose is to capture the canonical_class_name in a group and then alternating key=value groups. Currently it does not match a test string (in the following program, `testString`).

There must be at least one key/value pair, but there may be many such pairs.

**Question**: Currently the regex grabs the canonical class name, and the first key correctly but then it gobbles up everything until the last double quote, how do I make it grab the key value pairs lazy?

Here is the regular expression which the following program puts together:

```
(\S+)\[\s*(\S+)\s*=\s*"(.*)"\s*(?:\s*,\s*(\S+)\s*=\s*"(.*)"\s*)*\]
```

Depending on your preference you may find the programs version easier to read.

If my program is passed the String:

```
org.myobject[key1=\"value1\", key2=\"value2\", key3=\"value3\"]
```

...these are the groups I get:

```
Group1 contains: org.myobject<br/>
Group2 contains: key1<br/>
Group3 contains: value1", key2="value2", key3="value3<br/>
```

One more note, using `String.split()` I can simplify the expression, but I'm using this as a learning experience to better my regex understanding, so I don't want to use such a short cut.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class BasicORMParser {
     String regex =
            "canonicalName\\[ map (?: , map )*\\]"
            .replace("canonicalName", "(\\S+)")
            .replace("map", "key = \"value\"")
            .replace("key", "(\\S+)")
            .replace("value", "(.*)")
            .replace(" ", "\\s*"); 

    List<String> getGroups(String ormString){
        List<String> values = new ArrayList();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(ormString);
        if (matcher.matches() == false){
            String msg = String.format("String failed regex validiation. Required: %s , found: %s", regex, ormString);
            throw new RuntimeException(msg);
        }
        if(matcher.groupCount() < 2){
            String msg = String.format("Did not find Class and at least one key value.");
            throw new RuntimeException(msg);
        }
        for(int i = 1; i < matcher.groupCount(); i++){
            values.add(matcher.group(i));
        }
        return values;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You practically answered the question yourself: make them lazy.  That is, use lazy (a.k.a. *non-greedy* or *reluctant*) quantifiers.  Just change each `(\S+)` to `(\S+?)`, and each `(.*)` to `(.*?)`.  But if it were me, I'd change those subexpressions so they can never match too much, regardless of greediness.  For example, you could use `([^\s\[]+)` for the class name, `([^\s=]+)` for the key, and `"([^"]*)"` for the value.

I don't think that's going to solve your real problem, though.  Once you've got it so it correctly matches all the key/value pairs, you'll find that it only *captures* the first pair (groups #2 and #3) and the last pair (groups #4 and #5).  That's because, each time `(?:\s*,\s*(\S+)\s*=\s*"(.*)"\s*)*` gets repeated, those two groups get their contents overwritten, and whatever they captured on the previous iteration is lost.  There's no getting around it, this is at least a two-step operation. For example, you could match all of the key/value pairs as a block, then break out the individual pairs.

One more thing. This line:

```
if(matcher.groupCount() < 2){
```

...probably isn't doing what you think it does.  `groupCount()` is a static property of the Pattern object; it tells how many capturing groups there are in the regex.  Whether the match succeeds or fails, `groupCount()` will always return the same value--in this case, five.  If the match succeeds, some of the capture groups may be null (indicating that they didn't participate in the match), but there will always be five of them.

---

EDIT: I suspect this is what you were trying for initially:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
    "(?:([^\\s\\[]+)\\[|\\G)([^\\s=]+)=\"([^\"]*)\"[,\\s]*");

String s = "org.myobject[key1=\"value1\", key2=\"value2\", key3=\"value3\"]";
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find())
{
  if (m.group(1) != null)
  {
    System.out.printf("class : %s%n", m.group(1));
  }
  System.out.printf("key : %s, value : %s%n", m.group(2), m.group(3));
}
```

output:

```
class : org.myobject
key : key1, value : value1
key : key2, value : value2
key : key3, value : value3
```

The key to understanding the regex is this part: `(?:([^\s\[]+)\[|\G)`.  On the first pass it matches the class name and the opening square bracket.  After that, `\G` takes over, anchoring the next match to the position where the previous match ended.

Comment: This is excellent.  Your intuition concerning the real problem and the group count were both correct.  Two more things... I wanted to avoid String split, but it seems to be required for dealing with the comma separated list of key value pairs in a simple way.  Is this correct? And before I was thinking that the groups would create lists of matched sets. Did something like List<String> = MagicRegexObject.match("(\S+?\s)", stringOfContent); If that wasn't clear I'm trying to say, I'd like it if there was some magical regex object that can match things and return a list of the matched objects...

Comment: You mean, like Python's `re.findAll()` method, or PHP's `preg_match_all()`?  As a matter of fact, every one of the major, regex-enabled languages has something equivalent--except Java. :-/  If it's the intermediate captures you're talking about, that's not happening either.  Java, like most languages/flavors, provides no way to retrieve them.  You'll just have to rewrite the regex to match the key/value pairs one at a time, like I did in my edit.

Comment: Well that answers everything for now.  As a matter of fact it was so well written I decided to learn from some of your other regex posts, and as a result up voted them too!

Comment: Thanks.  While you're at it, check out [tchrist](http://stackoverflow.com/users/471272/tchrist)'s answers.  And don't let the length of the posts discourage you; they're dense with good, pertinent information, clearly presented.

Answer (score 2):

For non-greedy matching, append a `?` after the pattern. e.g., `.*?` matches the fewest number of characters possible.